# good practices regarding downcasting in java

Tags: java

I have a set of operations. Every operation is a sequence of 2 steps. So, I have a base class which executes these two steps and all the operations extend this base class and provide the actual implementations for the two steps. Ex.

```
class Base {
    Step1 step1;
    Step2 step2;

    B execute() {
        A a = step1.perform();
        B b = step2.perform(a);
    }

    //Set methods...
}
```

Here Step1 and Step2 are interfaces and one can change the implementations for them to do different things.

I have the following questions:

- Every implementation of step2 takes instance of A as input which can also contain a derived type of A. So I need to do a downcast. Is it ok to do a downcast in this case or is there a better way to achieve this?
- Some implementations of step2 may not return any value. Is it ok if we have an empty class just for the type hierarchy and other classes extend this class?

Comment: Do subclasses of Base always use some particular subclass of A and/or B?

Comment: Mmmm, i really don't understand very well the question. Perhaps you could show some more code or explain it more deeper. Perhaps generics will help you to reach some safety type casting, but i really don't know.

Comment: I think I need to see a more complete code example.  I can't quite understand your description.

Comment: Yes every implementation of step1 will return a subclass of A amd every implementation of step2 will take input some subclass of A. Hence every subclass of base will use A

Answer (score 1):

## Question 1

Yes, that is ok. Every class which extends the class A or implements the interface A (what ever A is) will be "an instance of A". So it is perfectly OK to pass it to a method which needs an object of the type A. Nothing to worry about. This is how you should use interface and inheritance. There are different kind of "specializations" of the same super-class.

## Question 2

This is a question of your API design. If you want that this method *could* return null, you can do this. But you should document it very good!

A very new possibility in Java 8 are so called **Optionals**. You can use them if a method could return null and you want to force the programmer to keep that in mind. That would be the cleanest (and recommended) way. You can find an example and a description at http://java.dzone.com/articles/optional-java-8-cheat-sheet. Basically you would say that your method `perform` of the class `Step2` will return an Optional instead of the type:

```
interface Setp2 {
    public Optional<B> perform(A a);
}

// the optional will wrap the actual result which could be null
// since Java 8
Optional<B> b = step2.perform(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use generics:

```
interface Step1<T extends A> {
    T perform(T a);
}
interface Step2<T extends A, U extends B> {
    U perform(T a);
}

class Base<T extends A, U extends B>>{
Step1<T> step1;
Step2<T, U> step2;

B execute() {
    T a = step1.perform();
    U b = step2.perform(a);
}

//Set methods...
```

}

Regarding returning "nothing", the best way is to return `null`.